# Can someone explain how I might use this function call that includes a delegate?

Tags: objective-c

This is the prototype:

```
- (void)startDownloadingDataOfType:(NSString *) type fromURL:(NSURL *) url  delegate:(id <GetURLAsyncDelegate>) delegate;
```

There is a delegate set up with methods such as URLDidFinishDownloading and so on. However I stil don't totally understand delegates - I get their point, but I don't really know how to use them.

This function seems to contain a parameter to pass IN a delegate, but surely I want to extract one?

In the class where I want to call this function I essentially want to be able to trigger a method when the URL has finished it's download. What is the syntax for using this kind of function in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the delegate to the prototype will cause the method to be called on the supplied delegate.

If you want the method (URLDidFinishDownloading) to be called when the download is complete in the class you called it from, implement the delegate in that class and specify the URLDidFinishDownloading method.

Something like below - (note: my obj-c isn't the greatest, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
@interface MyClass : BaseClass<GetURLAsyncDelegate> {

}

@implementation MyClass

-(void)URLDidFinishDownloading  {
 ...
}

-(void)downloadData {
  [object startDownloadingDataOfType:@"..." fromUrl:... delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: so you have to create a delegate class that mirrors the other delegate class and pass it through? like little mini-objects that have sort of, inversely-inherited polymorphism?

Comment: You can have your current class implement the delegate as well instead of creating a whole new class just to be the delegate.

Comment: right, but the delegate in the class where I call the function should have methods that mirror the names of the delegate in the function's native class, right? and these get called there. right?

Comment: Correct.  If you post your class somewhere (https://gist.github.com/) I can try to explain better.